# Class prefers its private members more than OOP rules?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, access-modifiers

I have this simple code :

```
public class A
{
  int _private=3;
  public   A (B b)
    {
        b._private=5;
    }

}

public class B:A
{
}
```

*this code compiles*

- Via `OOP` - the `b` should *not* provide access to `_private`.
- Via private and `A` , `A` knows `_private` , but still the access is made through `b` !

what is going on here ?

Comment: Well, `B` is a _type_ of `A`, and `A` has access to its own variables... What you are doing is a real code smell (a base class using inheriting types).

Comment: @Oded: I wouldn't quite call that code smell - it is a usual pattern for describing hierarchies, to have e.g. a `Node` class with two subclasses `Parent` and `Leaf`, where every `Node` uses a `Parent` as a reference to its parent node.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - One of the few exceptions.

Comment: @Oded: Ok, agreed. That one's a frequent pattern, but I can't really think of any other major patterns that would incorporate such a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The private access modifier gives access to a member within body of the type in which it is declared. It does not matter that `b` is another instance. It is an `A` so methods declared inside of `A` can access `_private`. I will also note that this example is more or less straight out of the C# 4.0 spec, section 3.5.2 about accessibility domains:

```
class A
{
   int x;

   static void F(B b) {
      b.x = 1;    // Ok
   }
}

class B: A
{
   static void F(B b) {
      b.x = 1;    // Error, x not accessible
   }
}
```

I think of the OOP recommendations for information hiding being about specifying the contract for client code. Public is something that is supported. Private is an implementation detail. Here, we could modify the implementation of `A` by removing `_private` and client code would be unaffected.